# Two INF files for the same driver solution?

Tags: windows, inf

We have a NDIS miniport driver. We have the same source code for WS2016 and WS2019 right now.

We want to make a separation between the two during build. What we want different is that, each of them should be built using a separate INF file.

Can I link 2 different INF files to the same solution file and change properties in the solution/vcxproj to use the INF file depending on what I am building for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we are doing something similar.
You can take a look at https://github.com/virtio-win/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/tree/master/NetKVM

There are three inf files that are used based on the OS. You will see them as netkvm.inx, netkvm_no_RSC.inx, and netkvm_no_RSS.inx repository.

The project file defines different inf depending on the build target:
https://github.com/virtio-win/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/blob/26c5015550b0b0a5e8257634ebb415fb1790d64b/NetKVM/NetKVM-VS2015.vcxproj

Look for following properties in the project file:

```
<SourceInfFile></SourceInfFile>
<TargetInfFile></TargetInfFile>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps! 

Is there is a way I can differentiate between WS2016 and WS2019? In the current VS settings, both will be Win10

Comment: You can create additional configuration by copying Win10 configuration. You also might need it to use different versions of NDIS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2019 use "Copy settings from" option